# allogeneic organ transplant and the immune response

Tags: immunology, organs, transplantation, hla

What happens when an allogeneic organ transplant is performed on an immunocompetent recipient vs. when it is performed on an immunosuppresed recipient using a donated organ with immunocompetent cells?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No, it's a question I saw when reviewing organ transplant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is just as you'd imagine. In an immunocompetant recipient, a host-versus-graft reaction occurs. This is called *transplant rejection*. Single episodes (acute rejection) are easy to treat and rarely lead to organ failure. Chronic rejection is the leading cause of organ transplant failure. The organ slowly loses its function and symptoms start to appear. This type of rejection cannot be effectively treated with immunosuppressants. Some people may need another transplant.<sup>[1]</sup>

In bone marrow and other transplants, T cells in the allografts reconstitute T-cell immunity in the recipient. Unfortunately, these T cells recognize the recipient as 'non-self' and employ a wide range of immune mechanisms to attack recipient tissues in a process known as graft-versus-host disease (GVHD).<sup>[2]</sup>

> *Acute GVHD* describes a distinctive syndrome of dermatitis, hepatitis, and enteritis developing within 100 days after allogeneic hematopoietic-cell transplantation (HCT). *Chronic GVHD* describes a more diverse syndrome developing after day 100. In addition to allogeneic HCT, *procedures associated with high risk of GVHD include transplantation of solid organs containing lymphoid tissue and transfusion of unirradiated blood products.*<sup>[3]</sup>

GVHD is increasing due to the increasing number of allogeneic hematopoietic cell transplantations (HCT). More than 25,000 allogeneic transplantations performed annually. Given current trends, the number of transplants from unrelated donors is expected to double within the next five years, significantly increasing the population of patients with GVHD.<sup>[4]</sup> Yet the major complication, GVHD, remains lethal and limits the use of this important therapy.

Long-term immunosuppressants are usually the treatment regimen for chronic GVHD. Fungal, bacterial, and viral infections are a major risk with this treatment since the immune system will be suppressed for a very long time.<sup>[5]</sup>

<sub>[1] [Transplant rejection](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000815.htm)</sub>
<sub>[2] [Graft-versus-host disease](http://www.nature.com/nri/journal/v7/n5/full/nri2000.html)</sub>
<sub>[3] [Graft Versus Host Disease](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/429037-overview)</sub>
<sub>[4] [Graft-versus-Host Disease](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2735047/?iframe=true&width=95%&height=95%)</sub>
<sub>[5] [Graft vs Host Disease: An Overview in Bone Marrow Transplant](http://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/treatments_and_procedures/hic_Bone_Marrow_and_Transplantation/hic-graft-vs-host-disease-an-overview-in-bone-marrow-transplant)</sub>